# Is there a way to use unicode-math in a limited fashion?

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, mathspec

At the moment, I am using `mathspec` and some traditional math packages such as `mathpazo` to typeset my mathematics. The results are mostly satisfactory, but I would like to expand the repertoire of some of the math alphabets by replacing the traditional packages with fragments of Unicode math fonts; in particular I want to be able to use the blackboard bold letters and numbers from STIX for `\mathbb`.

Now, the problem with using the `unicode-math` package is that it is totally incompatible with traditional math packages: it insists on replacing all the existing math symbol macros with Unicode ones even when no Unicode math font has been selected yet. I am not yet prepared to switch over to Unicode math as my main mathematics typesetting system, as it is very hard to get it to reproduce my current output. Yet, `unicode-math` seems to be the only way of using fragments of Unicode math fonts in the way that I want; the `\setmathxxx` commands from `mathspec` expect old-style fonts with the styled glyphs in the Basic Latin block.

Comment: Related (by title): [fonts - How to get "XeLaTeX + unicode-math" output as close as possible to that of pdflatex? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125175/how-to-get-xelatex-unicode-math-output-as-close-as-possible-to-that-of-pdfla?noredirect=1&lq=1) (use only the Unicode input feature of `unicode-math` package, not the Unicode character output font)

Comment: Remark: One way is to use XeTeX/LuaTeX built-in to load the otf font files, then set the Umathcode values manually, although documentation in e.g. `texdoc luatex` is terse and assumes understanding of how the non-Unicode primitives work (documented in TeXbook).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, sorry for the slow reply here and for the brief answer. The answer is unfortunately not `:)`

Comment: I suspected as much. Oh well. Hopefully there will be more unicode-math fonts to choose from in the future!