# How to get "XeLaTeX + unicode-math" output as close as possible to that of pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdftex, unicode-math

I've started exploring XeTeX and the `unicode-math` package in order to use unicode in my input.

Of the six math fonts described in [unimath-symbols.pdf](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf), Latin Modern Math seems to be closest to what pdflatex produces. However, I've already noticed a number of differences I don't like, such as `\varnothing` (which is the same as `\emptyset` now), `\complement` and the `\mathbb` family.

I know about the `range` option of the `\setmathfont` command. Right now I use:

```
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range={"2100-"214F,"2201,"2205,"1D7D8-"1D7E1,"1D538-"1D56B}]{xits-math.otf}
```

But I'd rather use a single command, option or package that takes all symbols as close as possible to the `pdflatex versions'. I can then explore the different fonts at my leisure, with the certainty that there are no big surprises in my existing documents.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The appearance of symbols is decided by the font designer.

Comment: For most symbols, yes. But perhaps you misunderstand the question. --- Which font does pdflatex use for each symbol? And is there a simple way to get XeTeX to use the same fonts in the same situations?

Comment: With the traditional setup, `\varnothing` and `\complement` are taken from the AMS symbol font; the designers of Latin Modern Math had different ideas about those symbols.

Comment: Well, that accounts for two differences. :-) You wouldn't happen to know about a comprehensive list of such differences?

Comment: I can offer some code for displaying all symbols in a math font, but this would be an answer to a different question.

Comment: No, that wouldn't really help. But thanks. --- For now, I'll just take the differences one at a time as I encounter them. In fact, after fixing those few I mentioned in my question, there don't seem to be many left. --- I'll keep the question open, though. If someone gives an answer, it might prove useful to others.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because no reasonable answer can be provided.

Comment: @tohecz: I'm sorry, but is there any way in which this is not silly? **[1]** The question is obviously about LaTeX and follows the rules, so: on topic. **[2]** A reasonable answer to *"Is there a way to do this?"* might be *"No."*. **[3]** How does the inability to answer a question make that question off-topic anyway? --- I can understand the impulse to close what appears to be a dead-end question, but please find a better justification.

Comment: @mhelvens Please complain to StackExchange powers. I didn't come with the word "off-topic" here. Off-topic is a bad notion that is supposed to cover the cases when the question somehow doesn't "fit in". The question really appears to be impossible to answer, which makes it unsuitable for SE, or "off-topic", as the powers above call it.

Comment: @tohecz: Why is *"No."* not a legitimate answer here? Anyway, I asked the question to solve a real problem I faced at the time, and it literally follows all the rules listed in the 'Asking' section of the help center (I checked). It is not subjective. Moreover, it addresses an issue that people may yet face in the future. If you are hung up on the word "answerable" in the 'what to avoid asking' section, I find that a bit weak. The most you could say is that this question does not have an answer *yet*.

Comment: Well, I think this is a one for meta. I mean, if you open a discussion over this in meta, if you open it on meta, I'll support discussing it. I'm not 100% convinced that it should be closed and that the close reason is reasonable.

Comment: @tohecz: Truth be told, I don't personally need an answer to this one any longer. But I do find the decision to close/put-on-hold an illogical one. Plus, the question may yet be useful to others. So for the sake of tex.se (and to oppose illogic) I will open that discussion on meta. Though forgive me if I let it wait until tomorrow (*yawn*). --- All the best,

Comment: @mhelvens No worries. I hope you're not angry at me for casting the first vote and that you don't take it personally since it's not like that! G'night.

Comment: @tohecz: Oh, please. Don't worry about that. You're just trying to clean the place up. :-)

Comment: @egreg -- if the question *hasn't* been asked yet whether there is code to display all symbols in a math font, i'm willing to ask it.  the news that latin modern has elided `\emptyset` and `\varnothing` is very upsetting to me -- i had a long argument with the unicode folks (which i lost) about whether these were different, or at least different enough to be recognized as legitimate variants.  so i need to do some more research to find out whether such "merges" would affect ams publications.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In my opinion, `\emptyset` and `\varnothing` should be a stylistic variant of each other: I can't think to a document using both with different meaning.

Comment: @egreg -- i agree with that opinion, but was unable to persuade the unicode folks that the "variation selector 1" (or "VS1" = FE00) should be assigned for that purpose.  (the symbols to which VS1 has been assigned are described in [unicode technical report 25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr25/), "unicode support for mathematics", in table 2.9, p.28.)  i guess i'll try again.

Comment: Looks like that this question is a combination of  [calligraphic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127216/250119) + [blackboard bold](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/360607/250119) + [empty set symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208014/250119). I can't find one for complement

Comment: For collection, there can be other differences as well regarding delimiter size https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647491/unicode-math-delimiters

Comment: and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120065/250119 for mathcal/mathscr