# How to use mmap in XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, unicode, unicode-math, copy-paste

I want to map math characters in my PDF output to Unicode characters. XeLaTeX already does this somewhat, but with very unsatisfactory results.

Just for comparison, consider the very simple example `$\mathbb E[X] = \sum_x x p(x)$`.

1. As baseline, Plain PDFLaTeX gives:

```
E[X] =
P
x xp(x)
```

2. PDFLaTeX + `\usepackage[noTeX]{mmap}` gives:

```
[] =
Σ︀
 ()
```

3. Plain XeLaTeX gives:

```
E[X] =
Σ
x xp(x)
```

4 Finally, XeLaTeX + `\usepackage{unicode-math}` gives:

```
[] = Σ ()
```

However, I want to avoid `unicode-math` due to its font management issues (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125175/how-to-get-xelatex-unicode-math-output-as-close-as-possible-to-that-of-pdfla) and its related questions). Is there any way I can get behavior in 2 and 4 in XeLaTeX without changing math fonts?

Comment: You want something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/. They are very difficult. So have fun.

Comment: I don't think that xetex has something comparable to pdfgentounicode. Use unicode-math, if you care about copy and paste.

Comment: @Symbol1 I do not think so. I am trying to map math characters to Unicode math characters, not map them to LaTeX source.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As I mentioned in the question, I want to avoid `unicode-math`; or do you know how to switch off its main functionalities (font mappings) and only keep the character mapping?

Comment: No, as I already wrote: imho xetex has nothing comparable to pdfgentounicode. So either you use a proper unicode math font, or you accept the problems of the type1 math fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmap uses `\pdfglyphtounicode` to map the glyphs. xetex to my knowledge doesn't support it, but with lualatex you can use it. As mmap doesn't support lualatex by default you have to map a number of command names to the names of luatex with the luatex845 package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[noTeX]{mmap}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb E[X] = \sum_x x p(x)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works but gives a warning at `\begin{document}` line: `!!! No .cmap file found for TU !!!`. Why is that?

Comment: As I wrote mmap is not really meant for luatex, it gets a bit confused about the default font encoding. You could ask the the author to improve the luatex support.